# *Person* this, *Person* that— can it be used to vocalize annoyance?

Tags: phrases

I know this and that is a phrase used to list various unstated things. But I remember hearing another use of this/that in English shows. For example, two people are talking about going on a trip but Person A keeps mentioning that they have to take care of their baby, and they keep addressing their baby issue during the entirety of the conversation. Person B has enough of it and goes, "Baby this, Baby that. I get it, so please stop," This brings to my question, can this be used to voice annoyance?

Comment: "All I hear is football this and football that!!!  Enough about football already!"  Yep.  Doesn't even need to be about a person.

Comment: "Authenticity this, sincerity that, enough about you."

Comment: @cruthers In fact I would say that it's used less when talking about people than about physical objects or, more commonly, abstract concepts.

Comment: Yes, it communicates annoyance. Here are some examples in *[proper noun] this, [proper noun] that* form: [https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=100972401](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=100972401). But any part of speech — “words-as-words” — would work: *It’s always do-your-homework this, do-your-homework that.* *It’s always “but” this, “but” that.* *It’s always Me this, Me that.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, yes, it's used to express annoyance.

---

As a native speaker of American English, I am familiar with this expression. However, I can't find anywhere on the internet that documents it, though I can find plenty of examples with the right searches.

---

The expression "X this, X that" is always used to express frustration with whatever *X* is, in my experience. *This* and *that* usually function like a placeholder for the predicate of sentences, to make the point that *X* is too often the subject. Sometimes, *X* is an imperative verb instead and *this* and *that* are placeholders for the rest of the sentence after that (the object), and the expression shows frustration for being told to X too many times.

I would say that I predominantly hear this, as opposed to seeing it written down, a fact that is clearly shown in the examples I've found as most of them are either from spoken English or very casual and thus close to spoken English.

### From the internet, unknown dialects

Found via Google searches

#### Noun

- > "Baby this Baby that........." Enough with the baby crap guys! It's getting old...my rant is officially over! — [ArcheryTalk Forums](https://www.archerytalk.com/threads/freek-nasty-swamp-donkey-and-thumper.1257197/)
- > Baby this, baby that.. Fuck off plz. — [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/SafeMoon/comments/oq9pg9/baby_this_baby_that_fuck_off_plz/)
- > I got this shirt for my husband since football season starts in August 2021 and he’s football this football that and “wanna talk, talk football; if not, go away” — [Etsy comment](https://www.etsy.com/listing/628758263/football-t-shirt-football-gift-i-love)
- > "My mum was going crazy. 'Football this, football that', she used to say. My parents were a bit strict on our school results, especially mum." — [Football Ghana](https://footballghana.com/my-mum-was-not-happy-about-the-constant-presence-of-football-at-home-jordan-ayew)
- > hehehe, well my brother sef, is a football fanatic, same as my dad, all i hear is football this football that — [Nairaland Forum](https://www.nairaland.com/155843/ibkaye-why-hate-soccer) (Nigerian English?)
- > gawd more **** about football!!! I am sick of seeing football this football that BLAHHH!! — [GameFAQ Forums](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/197338-final-fantasy-ix/65426694)
- > Every time I turn around its video games this, video games that. All the forums I read are plague by video games. — [Kotaku discussions](https://kotaku.com/author/fahey/discussions?startTime=1398035939515)

#### Verb

- > Hearing bad advice.  This is just a given.  From day 1, I've heard it all.  Eat this, eat that, do this during sex, "just relax",  "It'll happen when God's ready", "pray", "I heard about a couple who adopted and then got pregnant"...the list is a mile long. — [Blogspot Blog](http://ourjourneytothebabybump.blogspot.com/2013/04/why-is-living-with-infertility-so-hard.html)
- > What is interesting about this book is that rather than a typical "do this, do that" tome, it's a narrative told in the form of a story. Sure, some of it is a little hokey ("frog farmer"? Really?) but the brilliance of this is that it gets the point across in a way that isn't all "do this, do that" or preachy. — [Amazon comment](https://www.amazon.com/The-Queens-Code-Alison-Armstrong-ebook/product-reviews/B00G8V7RC4)

### American English

Found via [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/)

- > women this , women that, their isnt a woman on the planet who knows how to be a decent female  — Comment on Men's Health article 50 Things Women Wish Men Knew
- > All he talks about is the Yankees. Yankees this, Yankees that. Get a life! — Spin City (1997 TV show)
- > In America it's bathroom this, bathroom that. Even a port john. What bathroom? — Northern Exposure (1994   TV show)
- > A couple hours on Facebook, you know, was wedding this, wedding that. — CNN's Grace (TV)
- > Know what cracks me up about commies? They're all' equality this, equality that,' and they're all chauvinists. — [Collateral Damage](https://imsdb.com/scripts/Collateral-Damage.html) (2002 movie)

### British English

Found via the [BNC](https://www.english-corpora.org/bnc/). Even with the least restrictive searches (e.g. `this PUNC NOUN that` and `NOUN this NOUN that`) I can think of, I can't find more examples here. Not sure if this reflects the small corpus size or if it's just unheard of in British English

- > It's always milkman this, and cream of that. Or they call me Ernie. They tease me in the pub... it's always milkman this, milkman that. — 3895 s-units (Central television news)